# How to setup OperatorHub on ARO

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat

I've deployed openshift ARO via Azure.
Now I will like to add some operators into it - such as ArgoCD and linkerd.

But I cannot connect to the OperatorHub.
Going under Administration -> Cluster Settings -> OperatorHub I have four sources:
certified-operators, community-operators, redhat-marketplace, redhat-operators
All were disabled, when I enable them I get "TRANSIENT_FAILURE".

I tried to add another source with this Yaml file:

```
apiVersion: operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: CatalogSource
metadata:
  name: operatorhubio-catalog
  namespace: openshift-marketplace
spec:
  sourceType: grpc
  image: quay.io/operator-framework/upstream-community-operators:latest
  displayName: Community Operators
  publisher: OperatorHub.io
```

And was able to conenect to it. but when I install any operator from this source it get stuck in status "unkown".

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: proxy issues maybe? troubleshooting OLM: look at your Subscription status (when you install an operator: subscription is the first object created). Eventually, there should be an InstallPlan: if present, check its status. Then comes the ClusterServiceVersion: if present, check its status. If you can't figure out what those mean, share those statuses here.

Comment: Hey @SYN, can you guide me more specifically ? the status always get stuck at 'unkown', the installation plan I did for Argocd is automatically with the operator, but even if I change it to manually and choose to install it only on argocd namespace it makes no different..

Comment: Sure, can you share those objects statuses?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have missed the step "[Get a Red Hat pull secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/tutorial-create-cluster#get-a-red-hat-pull-secret-optional)"

Without that you will have problems with Red Hat content. But Microsoft doesn't do it by default because of customer privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the below link to setup :

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/tutorial-create-cluster#get-a-red-hat-pull-secret-optional][1]

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/tutorial-create-cluster#get-a-red-hat-pull-secret-optional][1]

Check operatorhub after the steps then you'll see the community operators.